# Get definition of function from their calls in Python

Tags: python, scope, abstract-syntax-tree, inspect

I need to perform analysis of an AST of a function that calls other functions. How do I get access to the AST of the called functions?

Consider the following:

```py
from other import check

def f1():
  return 1

def f2():
  return f1()

check(f2)
```

With `other.py` as:

```py
import inspect
import ast

def check(f):
  ast.parse(inspect.getsource(f))
```

The AST will have the `FunctionDef` of `f2` with a `Call` node for `f1`, but I don't know how to get the `FunctionDef` of `f1`. Similarly, if there are variables in scope, I want to be able to get their values.

As far as I can see, I might need to look at the current scope/frame somehow, and get this information, but I cannot figure out how. I can use decorators on `f2`, if that'll help.

Comment: What's the context here - what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Simplifying it a bit, but think of it as a DSL: I want to be able to evaluate `f2` using a completely different mechanism than Python interpreter, so need to be able to look at the source of everything it's calling.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the inspect function I think, coupled with it's get source method.

Have a look here: https://opensource.com/article/18/5/how-retrieve-source-code-python-functions

You can get the list of possible attributes of an object by calling **dir()** on it. At that point you will get a dictionary with all the callables in that object. You can at that point find the ones that don't start with underscores and get the source of those.

Something like:

```
class Test(): 
    def __init__(self, test):
        self.test = test

    def test_funt():
        pass

attributes = dir(test)

for attribute in attributes:
    print(attribute)
```

This will give you the list of names that are callable in the class. Then you can use the **getattribute** method of the object. The get attribute method can be called on an object, by a string and it will retrieve the attribute in that objects scope, weather it is function or variable. Then you can get the type of that returned attribute and check if it is a function to get it's source. Doing **type(test.test_funt)** will return method for example.

Comment: I use `inspect` to get source of `f2`, but I don't know how to get source of `f1` from inside `check`.

Comment: I think for that you will need to do some class introspection where you go through the attributes of the f and find the functions you need

Comment: Trying to do that, but I'm not sure how to get to the class/scope of where `f2` is defined, and find live objects in that scope that I can `inspect.getsource` for. Can I lookup `f1` in using the execution frame?